# SnackBar com Action Button não alinhado ao texto

Tags: android, android-layout

Olá,

Gostaria de saber porque meu SnackBar não fica com o texto alinhado juntamente com o `ActionButton`, isso acontece **apenas** quando o texto é muito longo. Estou colocando uma imagem de exemplo. Vocês sabem como faço para o SnackBar ficar com seu conteúdo alinhado corretamente? Se eu pesquiso *"Android SnackBar"* no Google Imagens, vejo vários exemplos onde tem um texto de duas linhas o `ActionButton` está alinhado corretamente com o texto, e não abaixo, como na foto.

[image: SnackBar desalinhado]

Comment: Realmente, existem vários exemplos, mas nos exemplos a quantidade de texto grande está na descrição e não no texto do botão, acredito que esse seja o problema. O texto do botão de ação deve ter tamanho fixo e sem quebra de linha. Faça o teste.

Comment: Gênio é você? Rsrsrsrsrs. Caramba que questão simples mas parece que nunca iria pensar nisso sozinho. Muito obrigado. Substitui o "Tentar Novamente" por "Retry" e aumentei o outro texto. Tcharan, eis a solução. Só que agora vem a dúvida, qual texto posso substituir no lugar de "Tentar novamente" para representar a mesma coisa em português com poucas letras?

Comment: Outra coisa, poderia colocar seu comentário como resposta, para eu fechar a pergunta? Poderia também responder no SOE? O link da minha pergunta lá é este: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769867/snack-bar-with-action-button-not-aligned-to-the-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente, existem vários exemplos, mas nos exemplos a quantidade de texto grande está na descrição e não no texto do botão, acredito que esse seja o problema. O texto do botão de ação deve ter tamanho fixo e sem quebra de linha.

*Aumente o texto de descrição e diminua o texto da ação do botão.*

Uma alternativa para o texto do botão de ação seria: *Recarregar*.

Ou ainda, você pode pesquisar como adicionar um ícone na SnackBar e tentar usar ele como botão, sei que é possível.